# Page not rendering in rails

Tags: html, pdf, ruby-on-rails-5

The problem with my *rails 5* app is that I have a link on a page that sends the user to `example.com/PlaceHolderRoute`. The route points to an action in the pages controller. The action is simply:

`send_file('public/files/downloadable.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline')`

I know that `disposition: 'inline'` will make the browser render the pdf, that is what I want and that's what it does. The issue is when the user uses the *browsers* back button. When the browser goes back to the page with the original button the pdf is still rendered on the screen & the page is not visible.

I've tried using a separate view for the action with an `<object>` tag for the pdf, but suffer the same problem. The page does become visible once it is manually refreshed. I've also tried using `<meta>` tags to prevent any caching to no avail. Something I also noticed is when the back button is used the URL in the browser does change and the server does respond as per usual. I think this a browser problem but I find that unlikely being this happens on every browser I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, Vivaldi, etc). Can anybody help me on this?

**Edit:**

This behaviour was not observed on Sinatra (still only using the same routes, html, & `send_file`)

Comment: Might it be turbolinks breaking stuff as it might try to recover from a cached state?